# Como puedo guardar datos en un array en c++

Tags: c++, array

El programa trata de un cajero automático, que cuenta con 5 opciones: 1 consultar saldo. 2 Retirar dinero. 3 Depositar dinero. 4 mostrar últimos 5 movimientos. 5 salir. Mi problema es en los últimos 5 movimientos, ya que debo guardar los datos es decir las consultas retiros y depósitos que el usuario haga, con límite de 5 y que cuando hayan ya 5 movimientos y haya uno nuevo, elimine uno y meta el nuevo movimiento al array.

```
void menu_de_operaciones(){
    
    
    
    cout<<"\t\t\t||------CAJERO AUTOMATICO---------||"<<endl;
    
    do{
    
    cout<<"\n1.  Mostrar Saldo"<<endl;
    cout<<"2.    Realizar Retiro"<<endl;
    cout<<"3.    Realizar Deposito"<<endl;
    cout<<"4.    Mostrar Los Ultimos 5 Movimientos"<<endl;
    cout<<"5.    Salir"<<endl;
    
    cout<<"\nIngrese la operacion que desea realizar: "; cin>>opc;
    
    switch(opc){
        
        system("cls");
        
        case 1: cout<<"\n\tEligio la opcion mostrar saldo"<<endl;
        cout<<"Su saldo disponible es de: Q. "<<saldo_inicial<<".00"<<endl;
        break;
        
        case 2: cout<<"\t\nEligio la opcion retiro"<<endl;
        cout<<"Cantidad a retirar: "; cin>>cantidad;
        retirar_dinero(cantidad);
        break;
        
        case 3: cout<<"\t\nEligio la opcion depositar"<<endl;
        cout<<"Cantidad a depositar: "; cin>>cantidad;
        depositar_dinero(cantidad);
        break;
        
        case 4: cout<<"\t\nverifique su archivo de texto si fue creado exitosamente..... "<<endl;
        ultimos_movimientos();

        break;
        
        case 5: cout<<"\t\tHasta luego, que tenga un buen dia :)"<<endl; 
        Sleep(1000); 
        system("cls");
        bienvenida();
        salida();
        break;
        
        default: cout<<"\n\nNo ingreso una opcion correcta, favor intentelo de nuevo en un momento...."<<endl; 
        Sleep(10000);
        system("cls");
        menu_de_operaciones();
        break;
        
    }
    

    
    
    
    }while(opc < 5);
    
}
```

Comment: Quisiera ayudarte, pero no entiendo bien tu pregunta, ¿Quieres guardar datos en un array?

Comment: Así es, eso es lo que quiero, guardar datos en un array

Comment: Arranca por definir el array que vas a usar e intenta ir guardando los últimos 5. Debes manipularlo como una cola, en donde el primero que entre es el primero que sale (si superas los 5 movimientos).

Comment: Gracias amigo, voy a intentarlo.

Comment: @Usuario Ya de hecho publiqué una respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para declarar un array se pone esta sintaxis: `[tipo de dato] [nombre del array] [tamaño del array]`. Por ejemplo: `string PersonasImportantes[5] = {"Juan", "Pedro", "Pepe", "Mario", "Maria"};` También, se puede usar la librería: `vector`, pero no me voy a meter en detalles con esa librería.

Ahora para acceder a los elementos, se necesita saber como se cuenta empieza a contar en programación. En programación se empieza a contar desde el número 0. Entonces si quiero acceder a un nombre del array tendré que poner la siguiente sintaxis: `[nombre del array] [numero a acceder]`. Por ejemplo: `PersonasImportantes[0]; //Es igual a Juan`.

Ahora para pedir datos fuera algo sencillo... Vamos a ver un ejercicio: Hacer un programa que pida 5 números y los muestre en pantalla (Con arrays).

Ahora veamos la solución:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
int numeros[5] = {0,0,0,0,0};

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
cout<<"Digite un numero: "<<endl; cin>>numeros[i];
}

cout<<"Mostrando numeros: ";

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
cout<<numeros[i]<<" ";
}

cout<<endl;

cin.get();

return 0;
}
```

Resumiéndote todo, para guardar datos en un array debes hacer esto:

1- Pedir Datos al usuario.

2- Ir recorriendo con un bucle con el tamaño del array para guardar los datos.

Y listo. Espero que me hayas entendido...

Comment: Gracias amigo, agradezco a todos por su ayuda. Espero seguir mejorando en c++ para poder ayudar a otros también

Comment: @Usuario Debes marcar marcar la flecha para darle puntos a ElBlackNinja por su colaboración, y así también para que aparezca que tu pregunta tiene respuesta. Y de nada :]. Y sí, espero que sigas mejorando, que un mundo de nuevas cosas increíbles te esperan!!